# POST request fails with insufficient authentication scope, while GET request succeeds

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API to make POST requests and update my Sheets. My code is working when I do GET requests, but the POST requests fail with the following error :

> The API returned an error:
>   Error: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Here is my code for the POST request :

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err)
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), postTest)
  })
  function postTest(auth) {
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth})
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
      range: 'A5',
      valueInputOption: 'Test',
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
      else {
        console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

My scopes:

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

Comment: Can you provide the script of function ``authorize()``?

Comment: Have you ever changed the scope in this project? For example, from `spreadsheets.readonly` to the current scope? Did you remove any serialized credential files from the relevant directory after doing so? Note that all update requests - even to public, anonymously writeable spreadsheets - require authorization with OAuth access tokens, while reads can be sufficiently authorized with just an API key.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the token.json file. I forget to delete it after changing my scopes. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I'd been having the same problem for a couple days, and I finally found it in my file system. I swear, I'd been looking around everywhere and no one had given a clear path to the file I had to delete.

So for the more novice programmers who found their way to Sheets APIs for whatever reason, I found it in:

```
~/Users/< MyUser >/source/repos/< MyVisualStudioProjectName >/< MyVisualStudioProjectName >/bin/Debug/token.json
```

I deleted `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user` in that folder and my write requests started working.